# Understanding Regex to fetch ip address :

Tags: javascript, python, regex

Regex 1: `\b(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.|\b)){4}\b`

Regex 2: `\b(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.|$)){4}\b`

Sample String :

```
123.105.114.142
010.000.000.011
240.000.000.240 121.122.221.123 224.152.255.152 
240.345.334.123

..@102.021.031.246@@@@@@02.021.031.246@@@@..@
255.255.251.255
10.1.1.2
23.124.23.144#
```

Regex 1 is able to fetch all the ip addresses from the sample string. My question is why regex 2 is not able to do so?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I tried that regex on regex101.com {4} means 4 times

Comment: Yes, I know, but WHAT 4 times. The 101 shows nothing when you have it in. The first one does have the preceding element 4 times - there are no 4 iterations of `([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.|$)` because of the $

Comment: `$` means the end of the string. If you remove `\b` and add `.` after all IPs in the input, your second one will also extract those IPs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I realized my mistake. My second regex will work only when my input is a string ending in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx where x is a digit.

Comment: Probably. Just read a bit more on regexes. See http://regexone.com - it is useful to learn the basics (as anchors and word boundaries). Use http://regex101.com to debug regex patterns (with PCRE option, it allows you to peek at what is going on behind the scenes).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for that pcre debug hack.